# How to map values between columns in worksheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I have the following worksheets

SPEARDSHEET FILE A
   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/153trbK2CvrUbEiIF2YZlAhskBq4MqQCckxAxutPOnEQ/edit?usp=sharing.

SPREADSHEET FILE B

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jjZEXSnskjiuZQdWYqnZGn4jwZS-6RUoY8sGacZq-88/edit?usp=sharing

I want to populate the WORKSHEET B with values from WORKSHEET A that corresponding Month. Note that months with 0 values are omited thus in WORKSHEET A there is no Month 5 or Month 10 by design.

How can I map the values between WORKSHEET B and A?

UPDATE

This is the closest I've come to it which imports the rows form WORKSHEET A into WORKSHEET B and tries to match the columns with the month and then return the values. but does not map it to the appropriate column

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(MATCH(INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("153trbK2CvrUbEiIF2YZlAhskBq4MqQCckxAxutPOnEQ","Cash Flow!A1:H3"))),A1:L3),A2:L3,2))
```

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b & https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Comment: Not sure how this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple INDEX/MATCH will do:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Cash Flow'!2:2,MATCH(A$1,'Cash Flow'!1:1,0)),0)
```

Put it in the first cell and copy over.

[image]

[image]

Note if your sheets are in different files replace `'Cash Flow'!2:2` and `'Cash Flow'!1:1` with:

```
IMPORTRANGE("YourURLString","'Cash Flow'!2:2")
```

and

```
IMPORTRANGE("YourURLString","'Cash Flow'!1:1")
```

respectively

Actual formula:

```
=iferror(index(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/153trbK2CvrUbEiIF2YZlAhskBq4MqQCckxAxutPOnEQ/edit?usp=sharing","'Cash Flow'!3:3"),match(A$1,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/153trbK2CvrUbEiIF2YZlAhskBq4MqQCckxAxutPOnEQ/edit?usp=sharing","'Cash Flow'!2:2"),0)),0)
```

[image]

---

BTW: HLOOKUP would do the work also:

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A$1,'Cash Flow'!$1:$2,2,FALSE),0)
```

[image]

[image]

NOTE if your sheets are in different files replace the `'Cash Flow'!$1:$2` with:

```
IMPORTRANGE("YourURLString","'Cash Flow'!1:2")
```

Now that you have shared the sheet:

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A$1,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/153trbK2CvrUbEiIF2YZlAhskBq4MqQCckxAxutPOnEQ/edit?usp=sharing","'Cash Flow'!2:3"),2,FALSE),0)
```

[image]

---

Another Option; SUMIF()

```
=SUMIF('Cash Flow'!1:1,A$1,'Cash Flow'!2:2)
```

[image]

[image]

This does not work cross files in google sheets.

---

My Cash Flows for reference:

[image]

Comment: They work on separate sheets, not separate files but different sheets in the same fill, they do.

Comment: IDK, I am not a mind reader. :) If the OP wanted different sheets in different files, then they should have said so.  Maybe the OP does not understand the use of IMPORTRANGE and is over thinking it.  Maybe...  We shall see.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am intact referring to separate files and not sheets. I think I have the terminology wrong? should I refer to files as spreadsheet and the sheets as worksheet?

Comment: @Kendall see edit for notes on how to use the first two with separate files.

Comment: @Kendall you need to also make sure that owner of the file has the rights to see and read the file which includes the data, or it will not work.

Comment: @pnuts see edit.  I included a note how to use the first two with reference to another file.

Comment: @ScottCraner this is cool but this will simply import the the row. I need the columns to map to the appropriate column based on the matching value of Month/ Month Period

Comment: @Kendall look at the latest edit on the HLOOKUP.  I have given the formula that works a picture that proves it.

Comment: @Kendall added actual INDEX/MATCH formula that works with photo.

Answer (score 0):

MS Excell has a function called HLOOKUP which may do what you need. I left an example for you here:
https://d.docs.live.net/8af110ba68997b6e/Documents/HlookupExample.xlsx

There's an explanation here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f

Comment: Could not see your example. The HLOOKUP is cool but does not map the values appropriately

Comment: @Kendall then you are using it improperly, or your desire and explanation are lacking.

Comment: Try to download the example from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6csh1v6v0mhex21/HlookupExample.xlsx?dl=0